How to bulk insert documents using the Elasticsearch Go typed client?
I am using the typed client of Elasticsearch using the official library. I want to bulk insert multiple documents. How do I do this?
This is what I wrote until now:
typedClient, err := elasticsearch.NewTypedClient(elasticsearch.Config{
        Addresses: addresses,
        Username:  username,
        Password:  password,
    })
bulk := typedClient.Bulk()
for _, doc := range docs {
    req := bulk.Index(indexName)
    req.CreateOp(types.NewCreateOperation(), doc) // This gives error
}
res, err := bulk.Do(context.Background())


https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/blob/main/_examples/bulk/indexer.go shows a good example with various configuration options.
To start, you want to use esutil.NewBulkIndexer(esutil.BulkIndexerConfig{}) to create a new bulk operator, and not the method above.

Maybe this example using batches is more relevant: https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/blob/main/_examples/bulk/default.go

@BrianWagner The examples you cited use the normal ES client whereas I am using the typed client which is different.

That doc page you cite states bulk is not supported. “The first version focuses on the requests and does not yet include NDJSON endpoints such as bulk or msearch”

"// This gives error" - which error?
